# WPAlchemy issue when using 2 select menus with the same values inside a repeating group

Tags: custom-field

I'm using v1.4.14 of the [WPAlchemy MetaBox PHP Class](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/). I have 2 select menus within a repeating group, `available_from` and `available_to`.

If I select Monday in the first select menu, Wednesday in the 2nd, and then save the post, the 2nd select menu's value changes to the first. So both become Monday. The initial values however are stored correctly in the DB upon the first save (Monday and Wednesday), but if you update the post again, they would be changed to Monday and Monday.

This happens when any day combination, but if I use the exact code below outside of the repeating group, it works as expected. I'm hoping someone has encountered this before and knows how to fix it. Really need the repeating group.

```
<?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('availability')): ?>
<?php $mb->the_group_open(); ?>

<label>Day (from)</label>
<?php $mb->the_field('available_from'); ?>
<select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" id="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
    <option value="">Select Day</option>
    <option value="Monday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Monday'); ?>>Monday</option>             
    <option value="Tuesday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Tuesday'); ?>>Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Wednesday'); ?>>Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Thursday'); ?>>Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Friday'); ?>>Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Saturday'); ?>>Saturday</option>
    <option value="Sunday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Sunday'); ?>>Sunday</option>
</select>


<label>Day (to)</label>
<?php $mb->the_field('available_to'); ?>
<select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" id="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
<option value="">Select Day</option>
<option value="Monday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Monday'); ?>>Monday</option>             
<option value="Tuesday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Tuesday'); ?>>Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wednesday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Wednesday'); ?>>Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thursday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Thursday'); ?>>Thursday</option>
<option value="Friday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Friday'); ?>>Friday</option>
<option value="Saturday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Saturday'); ?>>Saturday</option>
<option value="Sunday"<?php $mb->the_select_state('Sunday'); ?>>Sunday</option>
</select>

<div>
    <a href="#" class="dodelete">Remove</a>
</div>

<?php $mb->the_group_close(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<a href="#" class="docopy-availability button">Add new day range</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grab version [v1.4.15](https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy/tree/v1.4.15.20110909)

Comment: I could have sworn I checked github just in case you released a new version. Thanks so much Dimas, works great

Comment: I released it after reading your post above ;-)